# Routes with Custom Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, routes

I'm trying to work out how to get a custom route working with rails to perform a date query. I'd like to call this report if possible. So I access my route on the browser and get the following.

```
http://localhost:3000/trips/report

Couldn't find Trip with id=report
```

Like it's trying to read in report as an ID? I can't quite work out where I've gone wrong here? In my `routes.rb` file I've create the following entry.

```
match 'trips/report'    =>  'trips#report'
```

With the following in my trips controller.

```
def report
  @trips.all :condition => ["DATE(date) = DATE(?)", Time.now]

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @trips }
  end
end
```

I'm probably doing something very silly! Hopefully someone can help me along the right track?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly have declared a `trips` resource in your `routes.rb`, and the route `GET 'trips/:id'` generated by the resource have a higher priority then the `match 'trips/report'` defined later (Rails uses the first matching rule). If it's the case, declare your `report` route like this:

```
resources trips do 
  collection do
    get 'report'
  end
end
```

Look at [this chapter in Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for replying Baldrick! I've made this change and checked out the document, it runs OK but I still seem to have the same issue? Do I need to put this route before my resources :trips on it's own?

Comment: @davessh The code in my answser should replace both the `resources trips` and the `match 'trips/report' => 'trips#report'`. If you're in dev environment, you should not need to restart server. If if it does not work, post in your question your full `routes.rb`, and the full console log generated by the request.